# Angular 4 dynamically loaded components using attribute directive are wrapped with div

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to dynamically create some components based on the configuration options. To be more specific I want to have some toolbar, which can contain different "toolbar items".

As per angular guide: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html 
I 've created dedicated directive

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[mte-toolbar-item-host]'
})
export class ToolbarItemDirective {

    constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
    }
}
```

which will be used to indicate the "injection" point for the components.

I have the main `ToolbarComponent`

```
@Component({
    selector: "mte-toolbar",
    templateUrl: "./toolbar.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./toolbar.component.css"],
    providers: [ToolbarService]
})
export class ToolbarComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    toolbar: Toolbar;

    @ViewChild(ToolbarItemDirective)
    toolbarItemHost: ToolbarItemDirective;

    constructor(private toolbarService: ToolbarService, private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.toolbar = new Toolbar(this.toolbarService.getToolbarItems());
        for (let i in this.toolbar.items) {
            let toolbarItem = this.toolbar.items[i];
            let toolbarItemFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(toolbarItem.componentType);
            let componentRef = this.toolbarItemHost.viewContainerRef.createComponent(toolbarItemFactory);
            componentRef.instance.toolbarItem = toolbarItem;
        }
    }
}
```

with appropriate template

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li role="presentation" mte-toolbar-item-host></li>
</ul>
```

For now, the `toolbarService` is returning the following list of the components:

```
export const DEFAULT_TOOLBAR_ITEMS: ToolbarItem[] = [
    new GlyphToolbarItem(GlyphToolbarItemComponent, "example-component-id-1", null, "glyphicon-log-in"),
    new GlyphToolbarItem(GlyphToolbarItemComponent, "example-component-id-2", null, "glyphicon-floppy-remove"),
    new GlyphToolbarItem(GlyphToolbarItemComponent, "example-component-id-3", null, "glyphicon-log-in"),
    new GlyphToolbarItem(GlyphToolbarItemComponent, "example-component-id-4", null, "glyphicon-paste")
];

@Injectable()
export class ToolbarService {

    getToolbarItems(): ToolbarItem[] {
        return DEFAULT_TOOLBAR_ITEMS;
    }

}
```

`GlyphToolbarItem`:

```
export class GlyphToolbarItem extends ToolbarItem {
    glyphIcon: string;

    constructor(componentType: Type<any>, id: string, command: AbstractCommand, glyphIcon: string) {
        super(componentType, id, command);
        this.glyphIcon = glyphIcon;
    }
}
```

`GlyphToolbarItemComponent`:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[mte-glyph-toolbar-item]',
    templateUrl: './glyph-toolbar-item.component.html'
})
export class GlyphToolbarItemComponent {
     toolbarItem: ToolbarItem;
}
```

its template

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon {{toolbarItem.glyphIcon}}"></a>
```

I was expecting to receive something like:

```
<ul _ngcontent-c2="" class="nav nav-pills"><!---->
    <li role="presentation" mte-glyph-toolbar-item="" ng-version="4.0.3">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" mte-glyph-toolbar-item="" ng-version="4.0.3">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" mte-glyph-toolbar-item="" ng-version="4.0.3">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" mte-glyph-toolbar-item="" ng-version="4.0.3">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-paste"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

but instead I've received the dynamic components wrapped with the `<div>`:

```
<ul _ngcontent-c2="" class="nav nav-pills"><!---->
<div mte-glyph-toolbar-item="" ng-version="4.0.3">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></a>
</div>
<div mte-glyph-toolbar-item="" ng-version="4.0.3">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></a>
</div>
<div mte-glyph-toolbar-item="" ng-version="4.0.3">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></a>
</div>
<div mte-glyph-toolbar-item="" ng-version="4.0.3">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-paste"></a>
</div>
```

Why am I receiving the dynamic components wrapped with the `<div>` instead of the `<li>` element (which seems to be totally ignored)? Is this the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to GlyphToolbarItemComponent:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'li[mte-glyph-toolbar-item]',
    template: '<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon {{toolbarItem.glyphIcon}}"></a>'
})
export class GlyphToolbarItemComponent {
  @HostBinding('attr.role') role ="presentation";
  toolbarItem: ToolbarItem;
}
```

and remove empty li + move mte-toolbar-item-host to ul>ng-container

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <ng-container mte-toolbar-item-host></ng-container>
</ul>
```

Also I think Angular won't like that you create these components in ngAfterViewInit

I created https://plnkr.co/edit/8cjlzooO1Oh2CWydxbSN?p=info

Comment: That did the job. And you were right, I didnit spot that Angular was complaining on `ngAfterViewInit` earlier - changed to the `ngOnInit` and everything works correctly. Moving the `mte-toolbar-item-host` to the `ul` won't work because the dynamic components will be loaded as a siblings not as a children.

Comment: please check https://plnkr.co/edit/8cjlzooO1Oh2CWydxbSN?p=info - i moved to ul and it works

Comment: I can see that the `li` elements are put next to the `ul` and not within it <mte-toolbar>
    <button>Create</button>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" mte-toolbar-item-host=""></ul>
    <li mte-glyph-toolbar-item="" role="presentation">
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon-log-in">AAAA</a>
    </li>
    ...
</mte-toolbar>

Comment: u are right. i changed to     <ul class="nav nav-pills">
      <ng-container mte-toolbar-item-host></ng-container>
    </ul>

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what element it is you get the `ViewContainerRef` element from. `createComponent` will add a sibling and use the selector of the dynamically created component as element. Because no element is given in the selector `<div>` is used by default.

If you change the selector from

```
selector: '[mte-glyph-toolbar-item]',
```

to

```
selector: 'li[mte-glyph-toolbar-item]',
```

or

```
selector: 'li',
```

you will get a `<li>` element.